# Octopress not loading css

Tags: nginx, octopress

i'm having an issue configuring Octopress on Nginx

When i run `rake preview`
everything runs correctly i can acces `http://xxx:4000` and the blog looks just fine

when i run `rake deploy` i can still access blog on `http://xxxx/octopress`
but looks like no css/js 
[image]

when i explore the code and try to reach screen.css the link to css is `http://xxxx/stylesheets/screen.css`  but it must be `http://xxxx/octopress/stylesheets/screen.css`

here are the extract on Rakefile and _config.yml

conf

```
# ----------------------- #
#      Main Configs       #
# ----------------------- #

url: http://xxxxx/octopress/
title: Lux Baptiste
subtitle: Moui Moui
author: Lux
simple_search: https://www.google.com/search
description:
```

rake

```
## -- Rsync Deploy config -- ##
# Be sure your public key is listed in your server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file
ssh_user       = "root@XXXX"
ssh_port       = "22"
document_root  = "/var/www/octopress/"
rsync_delete   = false
rsync_args     = ""  # Any extra arguments to pass to rsync
deploy_default = "rsync"
```

i join my nginx serverblock, dunno if it can help

```
server {
    ### This setting tells Nginx to use this configuration if it gets a request for
    ### yourblog.com
    server_name _;

    ### This is the location on the web server where your Octopress files are
    ### published. Setting this here means you don't have to set it for any of the
    ### individual locations you define below.
    root /var/www/octopress;

    ### This tells Nginx to use "index.html" as the default index page everywhere
    index index.html;

    ### This disables automatic directory index creation, since no one will be
    ### browsing your directories anyway
    autoindex off;

    ### Here we define the root location...
    location / {
    ### ...and then work some magic with "try_files", telling Nginx that for every
    ### request that comes in to /, it should first try to serve the URI exactly
    ### as it is, and if it doesn't find anything by that name to then try and
    ### serve the URI as a directory, and if it doesn't find a directory by that
    ### name to then spit out a 404 error and give up.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    ### This location definition prevents Nginx from serving any files which begin
    ### with a dot, and further to not log any access attempts or 404s for files
    ### which begin with dots, to keep your access and error logs clean.
    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    ### This location definition prevents Nginx from serving any files which begin
    ### with a dollar sign, so Nginx will refuse to serve out a temp file if you
    ### are doing any editing inside a web-available directory
    location ~ ~$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }
    ### These next two locations simply prevent Nginx from logging every time the
    ### favicon & robots.txt files are accessed, to keep the logs clean
    location = /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/

Comment: yep, i was missing this, fixed now, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, just needed to change those lines in _config.yml

```
# ----------------------- #
#    Jekyll & Plugins     #
# ----------------------- #

# If publishing to a subdirectory as in http://xxx/project set 'root: /project'
root: /octopress/public
```